# Can password_hash() be replicated with crypt() in PHP 5.3.7?

Tags: php, encryption, hash

A commentator in the [PHP-manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) on the password_hash()-function that was implemented in PHP 5.5 suggested, that the following code can actually replicate the algorithm:

```
<?php

$salt = mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
$salt = base64_encode($salt);
$salt = str_replace('+', '.', $salt);
$hash = crypt('rasmuslerdorf', '$2y$10$'.$salt.'$');

echo $hash;
```

Is this safe?

Comment: Use this instead: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Comment: Note that the password_compat library @JohnConde referenced is also explicitly recommended in the [PHP.net Password Hashing FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you can get the same output for the same input then a password based key derivation function can be considered safe. Note that different implementations may handle character encoding differently (even those on major platforms such as Java and C#) so please test with all the characters you allow or consult the documentation or source code.

I won't go into side channel attacks as most implementations of KDF's don't consider them either.

Comment: But beware of time based attacks on systems that use CPU time sharing.

Comment: As I understand from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_channel_attack), "A timing attack watches data movement into and out of the CPU, or memory, on the hardware running the cryptosystem or algorithm. Simply by observing variations in how long it takes to perform cryptographic operations, it might be possible to determine the entire secret key. Such attacks involve statistical analysis of timing measurements, and have been demonstrated across networks." How would you protect against that?

Comment: The most common wayc is not to put the code on a time sharing system :) Furthermore there are tricks to make code run in e.g. constant time. Note that symmetric algorithms are a lot harder to attack than asymmetric algorithms such as RSA (modular exponentiation is especially susceptible to timing attacks).

Comment: If you relate this to the [password_compat-library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat), how would this look like? For example, what the function allows you is to set a cost like so: `$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 14);`. If I see this correctly, the hashing algorithm would produce different timing outputs depending on the server-hardware. But doesn't it make it more predictable for the attacker in this way?

Comment: Well, kind of. The more data, the more information that can be used for an attack. But I would not be overly worried. The attacker first needs to have access to the CPU. That rules out a lot of attack vectors. The biggest issue is when an attacker can retrieve the input of the hash algorithm or symmetric cipher. The first iteration would include the password itself. That would normally require a lot of runs as most time based attacks rely on statistics. As said, it remains to be seen if these kind of attacks are realistic, but if unsure, run on a separate CPU.